# Change results of SQL query in ASP page to include links for a specific column

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Apologies, this is kind of a convoluted question. I have a SQL query in a ASP web-page, which is returning a dataset to a webgrid in the page.  Looks like so:

[Picture of Dataset/Webgrid output in ASP webpage here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/myp3cey3431xt8v/webgrid.png)

I'd like to be able to take the "Community" column and keep the output the same, but make the output into a link to a software client based on the specific Community thats listed.  We have a short list of them (maybe 4-5 total) so it'll mean only 4-5 different downloads.

Additionally, I may need to include a field for the OS as we have different downloads per OS (Mac / Windows).  I assume if I can get the logic set for one, I can probably repeat that for the other column.

Any ideas on how I could approach this?  I'm just not sure how to phrase this question appropriately, but I think this might make it more clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the existing query, the table structure, and what kind of database you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you would need to do is something like

```
SELECT account, telephone, "<a href='"+communityURL+"'>"+community+"</a>" as CommunityCol, status
FROM myTable
ORDER BY account
```

... so, assuming the URL is described in communityURL the output you get in the CommunityCol column (from memory you might need to rename it) is a concatenated string containing what you need

Comment: Ahh ok, perfect.  Thank you for the help, I'll attempt this shortly and update if I'm able to make it work.